# What is the OpenServo good for?

Tags: servo

I found question [OpenServo and I2C Syncronization](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/21482/openservo-and-i2c-syncronization) here and I am curious what is OpenServo good for?

According to [OS Tutorial](http://www.openservo.com/ConstructionTutorial), you have to remove original board from your servo and install OS board. But what is the benefit? Why should I use OS instead of original electronics in servo?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Openservo is for people who want increased pecision of control of servo position and speed, a "command set" that can be implemented **by** the servo electronics and the ability to modify the provided intelligence that is inside the servo to allow it to do almost anything that it potentially can do.

There are large amounts of material on the web about what the OpenServo system is good for. A few good examples are given below.

Here is the [home page for the OpenServo project](http://www.openservo.com/).
  It provides many links to relevant documentation, a Wiki, user forum and more.

From the same site here is [a good OpenServo links page](http://www.openservo.com/FrontPage)  to related material.

Here's  a page that provides [links to a few end user applications](http://www.openservo.com/Applications)

[Here](http://www.phenostream.com/Products/OSM_01.aspx)  is "Open stepper" which has grown out of open servo code.

---

**The OpenServo people say:**

[OpenServo](http://www.openservo.com/) is an open community-based project with the goal of creating a high quality digital servo for robotics.

- Some of the many features of the OpenServo include:

  -**High performance** AVR 8-bit microcontroller
  -Compact H-Bridge with high performance MOSFETs
  -**Precision control** over servo **position** and **speed**
  -I2C/TWI based interface for control and feedback
  -**Feedback** of position, speed, voltage and power
  -**Advanced curve based motion** profile support
  -**EEPROM storage of servo configuration** information
  -**Software written in C** using **free development tools**
  -I2C/TWI **bootloader and GUI programmer**

[Documentation page](http://www.openservo.com/StepByStep)
 [SparkFun index page](http://www.sparkfun.com/products/9014)
 [Circuit of sparkFun implementation.](http://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/OpenServo/openservo.pdf)